# Downloading all the pdf file from website with Python 3 part.2

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, web-scraping, download

I rewrote the program so it would work after URL  gets redirected, but I am unable to save the file aka see it in downloads folder. This is website https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/1339#518552

```
       from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
       import urllib3
       urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
       import re
       from urllib import request
       import requests
       import time

       #access the website
       http = urllib3.PoolManager()
       url='https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/1339#518552/title/1339/item/558539'
       response = http.request('GET', url)
       soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data)

       download_links=[]
       #i found the part of the name files share and tried to append with that
       for link in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("/title/1339/item/5")}):
       download_links.append('https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/'+link.get('href'))

       # this part deals with redirected page
       #I am trying to make it work for only one link first.
       response_two= http.request('GET', download_links[1])
       soup = BeautifulSoup(response_two.data)


       for link in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("/files/docs/publications/cfc/")}):
             urlfin="https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/" + link['href']
             request.urlretrieve(urlfin)
```

The program runs but nothing gets downloaded could anybody help to find the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Select the filename for streaming.

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve(urlfin, "test.pdf")
```